# Why is my API Manager throwing an error when I use the .bat command?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I try to run the api-manager.bat command from the bin folder on my cmd I get the following error.

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.6.0\jdk\jdk-11.0.5
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\APIMAN~1\318FB7~1.0\bin\..
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=.\lib\endorsed;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.6.0\jdk\jdk-11.0.5\jre\lib\endorsed;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.6.0\jdk\jdk-11.0.5\lib\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have no idea what this means as my JAVA_HOME is set in my system variables and my identity server and enterprise integrator run perfectly. I have tried different versions of API Manager and the outcome is the same.

Comment: Please format the text in your question to clearly separate environment variables, command-lines, and error message output - right now it looks like your `CARBON_HOME` evironment-variable _contains_ an error message.

Answer (score 0):

It is pointing to your Integration Studio's JAVA_HOME and not your machine's JAVA_HOME.

Do the export directly in the .bat file at the beginning, and do the test to see if it resolves.

If you decide to adjust your JAVA_HOME in your environment variables.